# How to declare variable and enum declaration in one line?

Tags: ios, swift2

Is there a way to simplify this into one line in Swift 2.0?

```
enum Direction {
    case Up
    case Down
}
var panDirection: Direction?
```

Something like this, which doesn't work:

```
var panDirection = enum Direction {
     case Up
     case Down
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you could do it, those are not the same at all. `enum` is an object type, like `class`. In your first example, `panDirection` is an *instance* of the Direction enum. In your second example, if it could compile and run, `panDirection` would end up as the enum *itself* (the type, not an instance of the type) — which is not at all what you want.

Thus, what you are trying to do is to *declare a type* in the middle of a line. You can't do that. The rules for where you can declare a type are very clear and very strict.

Note, however, that you *can* declare a type within another type, or even purely locally, e.g. within a function's code. Thus, for example, you can declare the type temporarily as a way of passing data around inside a function. Nutty but legal:

```
func myCoolFunction(up:Bool) {
    enum Direction : String {
        case Up
        case Down
    }
    let dir : Direction = (up ? .Up : .Down)
    print("user wants \(dir)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, an enum type must be declared separately before it can be used as a variable's type.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the semicolon and not forget about epigram #3 of  A.Perlis: *Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon:*

```
enum Direction { case Up; case Down }; var d = Direction.Up
```